# Escape sequence for a space character in PHP

Tags: php, escaping

Currently I'm using the below snippet, which indent the resulting HTML by using several space characters:

```
add_filter('get_search_form', 'filter_search_form');

function filter_search_form($form) {
    $form = '      <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url('/') . '"><input type="text" placeholder="' . __('Search') . '" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s"><input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="' . esc_attr__('Search') . '"></form>' . "\n";
    return $form;
}
```

Now I've been reading some about whitespace characters (`\t` for tab, `\n` for newline, etc.), but I'm not entirely sure how to implement this in this situation.
I've tried using `\s` for a single space, but without any luck thusfar.

Being relatively new to PHP, I hope you could assist (preferably without using a 'regular' space character).

Comment: Hi! You are a member at Stack Overflow, how come you asked this here?

Comment: Hi @yannis-rizos, thank you for your reply. To me this looked like a more general question than just [WordPress](wordpress.stackexchange.com), and therefore I'm asking here.

Comment: It's specifically for PHP though so it's probably better off on Stack Overflow

Comment: you can read the FAQ for a  more in depth description, but generally if the question has code in it and the answer is likely to have code, then it belongs on Stack Overflow or another stack exchange site for more specific types of programming. this site is for more high level topics rather than specific implementation.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know there are 2 programming sections here at Stack Exchange. If a mod could push this question, this would be more than awesome. (not trying to be lazy, just like to see things nice and tidy)

Comment: @Cor -- You could always delete this question and ask it on stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't understand what you would like to do. Could you please explain better?

Comment: @entropy, in short I'd like to use something as `\s` instead of a regular space ` `, and was wondering if this would be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php, the general hexadecimal escape sequence `\x20` should work, as should `\040` (octal).

Personally, though, I don't see much (if any) benefit to ever specifying spaces in this manner, as it would make your code less readable, IMHO.  Just stick literal spaces inside your single- or double-quotes (like you have now) and be done with it.

Alternatively, if you're trying to use whitespace to indent the resulting HTML code (as it seems you are), doing so in units of `\t` isn't the end of the world.

Comment: I understand your worries. As an example I've posted the smallest snippet I could find. For a larger snippet however it can definitely benefit on finding things back.

Answer (score 2):

Characters like `\t` and `\n` need to be in double quotes...

`$string = "\t" . '<form></form>';`

Comment: I realize that. If you could show me the space alternative to your reply, you would be more than awesome.

Comment: as far as a I know there is no alternative to a normal space in php...where are you trying to add a space?

Comment: Hi David, I was afraid of that. Basically, to make my code less messy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a tab before it you could use:

```
$string = "\t" . '<form>....';
```

(don't forget the double quotes, the single ones don't work with \t, \n and friends!)

If you want spaces, just use spaces!

```
$string = "        " . '<form>....';
```

It's html code, so they will be present in the source code of your page. They won't ‘collapsed’ into a single space.

Comment: Caveat: Using multiple spaces like in PHP like this will put multiple spaces in the resulting HTML code; however, the browser will then "collapse" the spaces in the HTML code into a single space _unless_ you put it in something like a `<pre></pre>` block.

Comment: I think that's the point, if I got it right: he wants them in the HTML code and not in the page, just to indent the code. :)

Comment: Just being thorough, since the usage isn't clear from the question.

Comment: Hi @entropy, I understand the double quotes. I was looking for a 'space' alternative for tabs `\t` to make my code more readable. Btw. you don't need to use double quotes for spaces though. Above example works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just copied and pasted. :P there's no need for an alternative since the usual ‘ ’ works fine! ;)
Your initial code was already okay.

Comment: @tim-parenti, actually, it quite is. It's about grammar and readability. It's your reply that isn't really clear (: I mean, could you tell _what_'s not clear about my question instead?